# Print answer key to multiple choice questions

Tags: cross-referencing, exam

I'm using the `exam` document class, and I'd like to print the letter of the correct answer. Something like:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

    \question This is a multiple choice question
    \begin{choices}
       \choice this is a choice
       \choice this is another choice
       \CorrectChoice this is the correct choice
       \choice this is another choice
    \end{choices}

    The answer is /theCorrectChoice

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

I've seen similar issues online but I haven't been able to find a good way to directly reference "the correct choice" the way you can reference /thequestion, for example. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could update `\CorrectChoice` to insert an incremental `\label`. However, this would mean that only the most recent `\CorrectChoice` would be returned through a `\theCorrectChoice` call:

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}% http://ctan.org/pkg/exam

\newcounter{correctchoicemark}% Counter to keep track of correct choice mark
\newcommand{\theCorrectChoice}{\ref{correctchoice-\thecorrectchoicemark}}% Print correct choice
\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{% Adapt \CorrectChoice to insert \label
  \let\oldCorrectChoice\CorrectChoice% Store \CorrectChoice in \oldCorrectChoice
  \renewcommand{\CorrectChoice}{%
    \oldCorrectChoice% Original \CorrectChoice
    \stepcounter{correctchoicemark}% Increment correct choice mark
    \label{correctchoice-\thecorrectchoicemark}% \label original \CorrectChoice
  }%
}
\let\oldoneparchoices\oneparchoices
\renewcommand{\oneparchoices}{%
  \oldoneparchoices% Original oneparchoices environment start
  \let\oldCorrectChoice\CorrectChoice% Store \CorrectChoice in \oldCorrectChoice
  \renewcommand{\CorrectChoice}{%
    \oldCorrectChoice% Original \CorrectChoice
    \stepcounter{correctchoicemark}% Increment correct choice mark
    \label{correctchoice-\thecorrectchoicemark}% \label original \CorrectChoice
  }%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

  \question This is a multiple choice question
  \begin{choices}
    \choice this is a choice
    \choice this is another choice
    \CorrectChoice this is the correct choice
    \choice this is another choice
  \end{choices}

  The answer is \theCorrectChoice.

  \question This is a multiple choice question
  \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice this is a choice
    \CorrectChoice this is another choice
    \choice this is the correct choice
    \choice this is another choice
  \end{oneparchoices}

  The answer is \theCorrectChoice.

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[`exam`](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam) provides a hook into the `choices` environment via `\choiceshook`. Updating this to redefine `\CorrectChoice` is one (clean) way of inserting the appropriate code to obtain a `\label` you can `\ref`erence. `oneparchoices` does not provide this hook, so a different method altogether is employed in order to redefine `\CorrectChoice`.

More work is required for this solution to work correctly with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Comment: how to list the answers in a separate sheet...???@Werner

Comment: @David: In what way? I think it's best if you ask a [follow-up question](http://goo.gl/vWjuk).