# Multiple Choice Answer Key in exam package at the end of document

Tags: macros, exam

I think this is a follow up question to:

[Print answer key to multiple choice questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116461/print-answer-key-to-multiple-choice-questions)

I am trying to create an answer key at the end of my `exam` class document where all the questions are multiple choice.  Thus, the correct answers are already encoded into the document, as `\correctchoice` instead of \choice.

What I want it to do is print a simple table at the end of the document with the question number in the first column followed by the letter of the correct answer (as indicated by `\correctchoice`).  I have gotten close, but the only answer stored is the last one.

I have been searching the similar questions, but the problem seems to be in storing the correct choice somewhere, along with the questionlabel and then retrieving it at the end.  I am one of those self-taught LaTeXers who cobbles together things I have found elsewhere.  This is what I have tried so far.  It has two problems, it makes every answer E and it doesn't automatically label the `\correctchoice`:

```
\documentclass[answers
]{exam}
\usepackage{forloop}

\makeatletter
\let\xa=\expandafter

\newcounter{numsolns}
\setcounter{numsolns}{0}

\newcommand\solu{%
  %Saves the parameter as a solution
  \stepcounter{numsolns}%
  %\showthe\c@numsolns
  \xa\xdef\csname soln-label-\roman{numsolns}\endcsname{\questionlabel}%
  \xa\long\xa\gdef\csname soln-\roman{numsolns}\endcsname{\thechoice}%
}


%The following is from the exam.sty with one change:
       \def\CorrectChoice{%
         \if@correctchoice
           \endgroup
         \fi
         \ifprintanswers
           % We can't say \choice here, because that would
           % insert an \endgroup:
           \begingroup \@correctchoicetrue
           \CorrectChoice@Emphasis
         \fi
         \item
         \do@choice@pageinfo
                \solu%
       } % CorrectChoice
       \let\correctchoice\CorrectChoice

\makeatother



\begin{document}


\begin{questions}
\question[5] Important Question 1
    \begin{choices}
    \choice 99
    \correctchoice 100 \solu 
    \choice 50
    \choice 1
    \choice none of these
    \end{choices}

\vfill 


    \question[5] Important Question 2.
\begin{choices}
\CorrectChoice 6 \thechoice  \solu
\choice 12
\choice 24
\choice 36
\choice none of these
\end{choices} \answerline \vfill

\end{questions}


\newcounter{loopcounter}
\setcounter{loopcounter}{0}

  \begin{center}
        \ifnum\arabic{numsolns}>0\relax
        \clearpage
        \vspace{1in}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
    Question & Correct Answer\\\hline
     \forloop{loopcounter}{1}{\value{loopcounter} < \arabic{numsolns}}{%
    \csname soln-label-\romannumeral\value{loopcounter}\endcsname&
                \csname soln-\romannumeral\value{loopcounter}\endcsname \\\hline}
                                \csname soln-label-\romannumeral\arabic{numsolns}\endcsname&
                \csname soln-\romannumeral\arabic{numsolns}\endcsname \\\hline

    \end{tabular}
    \fi
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

---

Thanks to the comments, I have a partially working example.

```
\documentclass[answers
]{exam}

%%%%The following sets up a box to save all the answer information into.
\newbox\allanswers
\setbox\allanswers=\vbox{}

\newenvironment{answer}
{%
  \global\setbox\allanswers=\vbox\bgroup%
  \unvbox\allanswers%
    \thequestion  \thechoice\\
}%
{%
  \egroup%
}

\newcommand{\showallanswers}{\par\unvbox\allanswers}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
\let\xa=\expandafter

%The following is from the exam.sty with one change:
       \newcommand{\CorrectChoice}{%
         \if@correctchoice
           \endgroup
         \fi
         \ifprintanswers
           % We can't say \choice here, because that would
           % insert an \endgroup:
           \begingroup \@correctchoicetrue
           \CorrectChoice@Emphasis
         \fi
         \item
         \do@choice@pageinfo %
       } % CorrectChoice

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%This interacts with the exam.sty to put the answer in the appropriate spot.
\newcommand{\corchoice}[1]{ \CorrectChoice  #1 \begin{answer}\end{answer} }
\let\oldCorrectChoice\CorrectChoice
\renewcommand{\CorrectChoice}{\oldCorrectChoice \begin{answer}\end{answer} }
\let\correctchoice\CorrectChoice


\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question[5] Important Question 1
    \begin{choices}
    \choice 99
    \corchoice{ 100}  
    \choice 50
    \choice 1
    \choice none of these
    \end{choices}

\vfill 


    \question[5] Important Question 2.
\begin{choices}
\corchoice{ 6} 
\choice 12
\choice 24
\choice 36
\choice none of these
\end{choices} \answerline \vfill

\end{questions}

\begin{center}
  Here are the answers:
\end{center}
\showallanswers

\end{document}
```

There are several issues with this:

1. I can't seem to change the \newenvironment to a \newcommand and it
       seems wrong to be using \begin{answer}\end{answer} as my way of
       loading the information into the box, but I can live with it.
2. I can't seem to change the definition of \correctchoice to use the new environment.  I have tried hacks like
       \let\oldCorrectChoice\CorrectChoice, but nothing I try seems to
       work.  This may be because I am using the exam.sty and I am trying
       to do something impossible.
3. In the event that (2) is impossible, I would really like to have a
   command that doesn't take extra data as I have now with
       \corchoice{}, but when I try that, the \savebox is eating the \item number.

Comment: @MariahBirgen Look at the three answers provided in this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15350/showing-solutions-of-the-questions-separately.  This shows several ways to accomplish what you want.  When you have it working, then post your solution as an answer.  Then wait a day or two to see it a more "elegant" answer appears.  Finally accept the best or most useful answer for you.

Comment: If you are using Linux, try [Auto Multiple Choice (AMC)](http://home.gna.org/auto-qcm/). Otherwise, try Linux plus AMC.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I am afraid Linux isn't a current answer.  I have made the second suggestion "sort of" work, but not very well.

Comment: Wow, this is definitely an example of where a little knowledge is a dangerous thing.  I think I have the problem solved after meditating on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57268/missing-item-number-in-enumerate .

Answer (score 2):

I started with the first answer to [Showing Solutions of the Questions "separately"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15350/showing-solutions-of-the-questions-separately) and modified it to something that is nearly exactly what I wanted.  It turns out that \item and \setbox don't play well with each other (read to the bottom of [Missing Item number in enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57268/missing-item-number-in-enumerate) for the details).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

%%%%The following sets up a box to save all the answer information into.
\newbox\allanswers
\setbox\allanswers=\vbox{}

\newenvironment{answer}
{%
  \global\setbox\allanswers=\vbox\bgroup %
  \unvbox\allanswers%
    \thequestion \thechoice\\
}%
{%
  \egroup%
}

\newcommand{\CC}{\CorrectChoice \leavevmode\begin{answer}\end{answer}}% New command \CC replaces \CorrectChoice from exam.sty and saves answers in the box \allanswers .


\newcommand{\showallanswers}{%
\ifprintanswers \centering Here are the answers: \par \usebox\allanswers \fi}


\begin{document}


\begin{questions}
\question[5] Important Question 1
    \begin{choices}
    \choice 99
    \CC 100
    \choice 50 
    \choice 1
    \choice none of these
    \end{choices}

% \vfill 


    \question[5] Important Question 2.
\begin{choices}
\CC 6 
\choice 12
\choice 24
\choice 36
\choice none of these
\end{choices} \answerline %\vfill

\end{questions}


\showallanswers
% The answers have the same text format as the answers within the question, so are naturally \textbf when 

\end{document}
```

The only thing that would make this better is to have the list of problem numbers and answers inside a tabular environment, but I am going to leave that for another day.

Comment: In the printing of question paper the correct choice is printed in bold type! Revealing the correct answer! How to avoid this?