# showallanswers doesn't print my document. No answer key

Tags: exam, answers

I am trying to make a nice exam template and everything is fine except that I can't print the answer key.

When I use `answer` (class option) or `\printanswers` there is an error.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
    \lfoot{}
    \cfoot{}
    \rfoot[]{\small pag. \thepage\ of \numpages}
    \footrule

%%%%The following sets up a box to save all the answer information into.
%% Give credit when  credit is due:%% 
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238153/multiple-choice-answer-key-in-exam-package-at-the-end-of-document


\newbox\allanswers
\setbox\allanswers=\vbox{}

\newenvironment{answer}
{%
  \global\setbox\allanswers=\vbox\bgroup %
  \unvbox\allanswers%
    \thequestion -- \thechoice\\
}%
{%
  \egroup%
}

\newcommand{\CC}{\CorrectChoice \leavevmode\begin{answer}\end{answer}}% New command \CC replaces \CorrectChoice from exam.sty and saves answers in the box \allanswers .


\newcommand{\showallanswers}{%
%\ifprintanswers 
\par  \usebox\allanswers}

    \renewcommand{\thequestion}{\bfseries\arabic{question}}
    \renewcommand\choicelabel{(\alph{choice})}

    \renewcommand{\thequestion}{\bfseries\arabic{question}}
    \renewcommand\choicelabel{(\alph{choice})}

    \renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{30pt}%
    }
    \renewcommand{\choiceshook}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{20pt}%
    }

%configuracao da pagina
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.8cm} \setlength{\textheight}{10in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\extrafootheight{.75in}

\begin{document}

    \section*{\Large  Bloco 1 - Mega Teste Eletrônica e Telecom}
    \noindent{\bf \hfill \today}
    \noindent\rule[\topskip]{\textwidth}{1pt}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\begin{questions}

    %Q1
    \question Um capacitor $C$ é submetido a uma tensão $V$. A energia armazenada no capacitor vale:
    \begin{choices}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
                \choice $CV^2$
                \CC $0.5CV^2$
                \choice $2CV^2$
                \choice $CV$
        \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q2
    \question Uma tensão DC é aplicada num circuito RL série. O valor da corrente em regime permanente é:
    \begin{choices}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \CC $V/R$
            \choice $V/L$
            \choice $\dfrac{V}{\sqrt{R^2+L^2}}$
            \choice zero
        \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q3
    \question A constante de tempo do circuito mostrado na figura abaixo vale:
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{q3.png}
    \end{center}
    \begin{choices}
            \CC $CR$
            \choice $2CR$
            \choice $CR/4$
            \choice $CR/2$
    \end{choices}

    %Q4
    \question Num Amplificador Operacional ideal mostrado na figura, V0 vale:
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{q4.png}
    \end{center}
    \begin{choices}
        \choice $2V_s$
        \choice $-2V_s$
        \CC $3V_s$
        \choice $-3V_s$
    \end{choices}

    %Q5
    \question Se a resposta de um sistema a uma entrada degrau unitário é uma função impulso unitário, então a função de transferência envolvida no sistema é igual a:
    \begin{choices}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \choice 1
            \choice $1/s$
            \CC $s$
            \choice $1/s^2$
        \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q6
    \question Três resistores de 6$\Omega$ são conectados conforme figura abaixo. A resistência equivalente entre os pontos $X_1$ e $X_2$ é:
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{q6.png}
    \end{center}
    \begin{choices}
        \CC $2\Omega$
        \choice $4\Omega$
        \choice $8\Omega$
        \choice $12\Omega$
    \end{choices}

    %Q7
    \question A fonte no circuito mostrado é de natureza senoidal. A tensões fornecidas a todos os elementos de circuitos são mostradas na figura abaixo. O valor da tensão total na fonte é de:
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{q7.png}
    \end{center}
    \begin{choices}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \choice $10V$
            \CC $5V$
            \choice $27V$
            \choice $24V$
        \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q8
    \question A transformada de Laplace da função $e^{-at}f(t)$ é:
    \begin{choices}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \choice $F(s)e^{-at}$
            \choice $F(s-a)$
            \CC $F(s+a)$
            \choice $\frac{F(s)}{s} + a$
        \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q9
    \question A função $\cos\theta$ pode ser representada por:
    \begin{choices}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \choice $\dfrac{e^{j\theta}-e^{-j\theta}}{2}$
            \choice $\dfrac{e^{j\theta}-e^{-j\theta}}{2j}$
            \CC $\dfrac{e^{j\theta}+e^{-j\theta}}{2}$
            \choice $\dfrac{e^{j\theta}-e^{-j\theta}}{2j}$
        \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q10
    \question As alternativas mostram funções de transferência de segunda ordem linear invariante no tempo. Qual a alternativa representa um sistema subamortecido?
    \begin{choices}
        \choice $H(s) = \dfrac{1}{s^2+4s+4}$
        \choice $H(s) = \dfrac{1}{s^2+5s+4}$
        \choice $H(s) = \dfrac{1}{s^2+4.5s+4}$
        \CC $H(s) = \dfrac{1}{s^2+3s+4}$
    \end{choices}

    %Q11
    \question Um amplificador operacional tem um ganho diferencial igual a $20.000$ e CMRR = $80dB$. O Ganho em modo comum é dado por:
    \begin{choices}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \CC $2$
            \choice $1$
            \choice $1/2$
            \choice $0$
        \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q12
    \question Duas lâmpadas marcam 200 watt – 250 volts e 100W – 250 volts respectivamente. Elas são unidas e colocadas em série com uma tensão de 250V total. A potência consumida no circuito é de:
    \begin{choices}
        \choice $33W$
        \CC $67W$
        \choice $100W$
        \choice $300W$
    \end{choices}

    %Q13
    \question Um diodo zener de 6V mostrado na figura tem uma resistência zener igual a zero. Sua corrente reversa vale 5mA. Qual o valor mínimo do resistor R de moro que a tensão aplicada ao referido diodo não seja menor que 6V?
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{q13.png}
    \end{center}
    \begin{choices}
        \choice $1.2k\Omega$
        \CC $80\Omega$
        \choice $50\Omega$
        \choice $0\Omega$
    \end{choices}

    %Q14
    \question Um circuito mostrado na figura cujo diodo zener tem corrente reversa igual a $5mA$, e o máximo de dissipação permitida é de $300mW$. Qual é o valor mínimo e máximo da corrente na carga, respectivamente que pode ser aplicada, de modo que sua saída mantenha um valor de $V_0=6V$?
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{q14.png}
    \end{center}
    \begin{choices}
        \choice $0mA, 180mA$
        \choice $5mA, 110mA$
        \CC $10mA, 55mA$
        \choice $60mA, 180mA$
    \end{choices}

    %Q15
    \question A tensão $V_1$ e $V_2$ no circuito mostrado abaixo valem respectivamente:
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{q15.png}
    \end{center}
    \begin{choices}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \choice $6V$ e $5.4V$
        \choice $5.4V$ e $6V$
        \choice $3V$ e $5.4V$
        \CC $6V$ e $6V$
    \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q16
    \question Um diodo \textit{zener} cuja tensão em seus terminais valem 24V, e corrente máxima de 600mA, está sendo usado para prover a carga sua referida tensão. Assuma que a corrente reversa mínima que flua sob o \textit{zener} é de 10mA. Se a tensão de entrada vale 32V, qual o valor do resistor R e da corrente máxima na carga, respectivamente?
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{q16.png}
    \end{center}
    \begin{choices}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \choice $320\Omega$ e $10mA$
        \choice $400\Omega$ e $15mA$
        \choice $400\Omega$ e $10mA$
        \CC $320\Omega$ e $15mA$
    \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q17
    \question Um meio somador pode ser construído usando 2 portas lógicas. Uma delas é uma porta AND. A outra é uma porta:
    \begin{choices}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \choice OR
        \choice NAND
        \choice NOR
        \CC XOR
    \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q18
    \question \Coffeecup Analise as opções abaixo e verifique quais delas descreve um Flip-Flop JK o qual seu clock pode ser usado como um divisor de 2 num circuito de trem de pulsos (divisor de pulsos).
    \begin{choices}
        \choice J=1, K=1, sendo ativado em nível alto.
        \choice J=1, K=1, sendo ativado em nível baixo.
        \choice J=0, K=0, sendo ativado em nível alto.
        \CC J=1, K=1, sendo ativado na borda de descida.
    \end{choices}

    %Q19
    \question O número de comparadores necessários para se construir um conversor A/D de 6 bits é:
    \begin{choices}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \CC 63
        \choice 64
        \choice 7
        \choice 6
    \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q20
    \question Um conversor A/D é usado como um voltímetro digital do tipo:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Aproximação sucessivas
        \item Conversor Flash
        \item Conversor de Dupla Rampa
    \end{enumerate}
    A melhor sequência que representa a ordem dos conversores de acordo com o tempo é em ordem crescente, ou seja, do menor para o de maior tempo é:
    \begin{choices}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \choice 1,2,3
        \choice 2,1,3
        \choice 3,2,1
        \choice 3,1,2
    \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q21
    \question O circuito abaixo é um:
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{q21.png}
    \end{center}
    \begin{choices}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \choice Monoestável
        \choice Astável
        \choice Somador
        \CC FlipFlop SR
    \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q22
    \question Qual numero binário representa o número octal 66.3:
    \begin{choices}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \choice Monoestável
        \choice Astável
        \choice Somador
        \CC FlipFlop SR
    \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q23
    \question A expressão da lógica booleana da figura abaixo é:
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{q23.png}
    \end{center}
    \begin{choices}
        \choice $Y = AB+\overline{AB}+C$
        \CC $Y = \bar{A}\bar{B}+AB+\bar{C}$
        \choice $Y = A\bar{B}+\bar{A}B+C$
        \choice $Y = \overline{AB}+\bar{A}B+\bar{C}$
    \end{choices}

    %Q24
    \question Para a identidade $AB+\bar{A}C+BC = AB + \bar{A}C$, sua forma dual é:
    \begin{choices}
        \choice $(A+B)(\bar{A}+B)(B+C) = (A+B)(\bar{A}+C)$
        \CC $(A+B)(\bar{A}+\bar{B})(A+\bar{C}) = (\bar{A}+\bar{B})(\bar{A}+C)$
        \choice $Y = A\bar{B}+\bar{A}B+C$
        \choice $Y = \overline{AB}+\bar{A}B+\bar{C}$
    \end{choices}

    %Q25
    \question O circuito lógico mostrado abaixo converte o código binário $Y_1Y_2Y_3$ em:
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{q25.png}
    \end{center}
    \begin{choices}
        \choice Código Excess 3
        \CC Código Gray
        \choice Código BCD
        \choice Código Hamming
    \end{choices}

    %Q26
    \question \WritingHand Um contador progressivo de \textit{4-bits} tem uma configuração de \textit{preset} igual a 0101. A operação do \textit{preset} ocorre tão logo o estado do contador alcance 1111. O módulo deste contador é igual a:
    \begin{choices}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \choice 5
        \CC 10
        \choice 11
        \choice 15
    \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q27
    \question Um contador síncrono de \textit{4-bits} usa \textit{flip-flops} com propagação de atraso de 25ns cada. O maior máximo possível para mudança de estado para este contador será de:
    \begin{choices}
        \CC 25ns
        \choice 50ns
        \choice 75ns
        \choice 100ns
    \end{choices}

    %Q28
    \question Se um contador tem 10 FlipFlops e estão inicialmente em 0. Em qual estado ele estará mantendo após 2060 pulsos?
    \begin{choices}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \CC 000 000 1100
        \choice 000 001 1100
        \choice 000 001 1000
        \choice 000 000 1110
    \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q29
    \question \Bat \Bat Um registrador de deslocamento é mostrado na figura está inicialmente carregado com o seguinte padrão de bits 1010. O registrador então é acionado com um clock, cada pulso de clock por padrão desloca a posição dos bits \textbf{para a direita}. Com esse deslocamento, o bit de entrada serial é então introduzido no registrador na posição do bit mais significativo (MSB). Após quantos pulsos de clock o valor da memória no registrador tornará 1010 novamente?
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{q29.png}
    \end{center}
    \begin{choices}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \choice 3
        \CC 7
        \choice 11
        \choice 15
    \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q30
    \question A lógica combinacional do circuito mostrado abaixo é dado pela saída Q cuja expressão é igual a:
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{q30.png}
    \end{center}
    \begin{choices}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \choice $ABC$
        \CC $A+B+C$
        \choice $A\oplus B\oplus C$
        \choice $AB+C$
    \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q31
    \question Um \textit{circuito sample-and-hold} (S/H), tem um capacitor de 0.1nF que é usado na entrada de um conversor AD. O tempo de conversão deste conversor é de $1\mu$ sec, o capacitor, nesse caso, não pode perder mais do que 0.5\% de sua carga durante o período de amostragem. O máximo valor de tensão de sinal de entrada para o S/H é de 5V. O valor da corrente que pode ser perdida (leakage current) neste S/H deverá ser menos que:
    \begin{choices}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \choice $2.5 mA$
        \choice $0.25 mA$
        \choice $25.0 \mu A$
        \CC $2.5 \mu A$
    \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q32
    \question \WritingHand Determine a tensão de saída no circuito mostrado na figura abaixo, sendo sua entrada igual a 1011.
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{q32.PNG}
    \end{center}
    \begin{choices}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \choice $-3.875$
        \choice $-4.875$
        \choice $-5.875$
        \CC $-6.875$
    \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q33
    \question Um sistema de memória de tamanho igual a 16K bytes é modelado por meio de chips de memórias, cada chip possui 12 linhas de endereços e 4 linhas de dados cada. O número de chips requeridos para suprir esse sistema de memória é igual a:
    \begin{choices}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \choice 2
        \choice 4
        \CC 8
        \choice 16
    \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}

    %Q34
    \question Na multiplexação por divisão de tempo (TDM):
    \begin{choices}
        \choice O tempo é o dobro entre um bit e um byte.
        \choice A divisão de tempo depende da performance que a CPU leva.
        \CC O tempo total disponível no canal é dividido entre os vários usuários e cada usuário aloca um determinado intervalo.
        \choice Nenhuma das anteriores.
    \end{choices}

    %Q35
    \question Reutilizar de outro teste

    %Q36
    \question A soma S de A e B em um somador simples pode ser implementada usando K portas NAND. O valor de K é:
    \begin{choices}
        \choice 3
        \CC 4
        \choice 5
        \choice Nenhuma das anteriores
    \end{choices}

    %Q37
    \question A relação de onda estacionária (SWR) de uma linha de transmissão é sempre:
    \begin{choices}
        \choice sempre menor que a unidade.
        \CC sempre maior que a unidade.
        \choice Zero.
        \choice Infinita.
    \end{choices}

    %Q38
    \question Um guia de onda age como um:
    \begin{choices}
        \CC Filtro Passa Alta.
        \choice Filtro Passa Baixa.
        \choice Filtro Passa Tudo.
        \choice Filtro Rejeita Banda.
    \end{choices}

    %Q39
    \question Uma onda eletromagnética de $100Mhz$ propaga por dielétrico não magnético cuja permeabilidade relativa vale $\epsilon_r = 9$. Seu comprimento de onda vale:
    \begin{choices}
        \choice 3 m.
        \choice 3 cm.
        \CC 100 cm.
        \choice 10 cm.
    \end{choices}

    %Q40
    \question Um modo TEM de uma onda existe:
    \begin{choices}
        \choice Num guia de onda circular.
        \choice Num guia de onda retangular.
        \CC Num cabo coaxial
        \choice Em nenhuma linha de transmissão.
    \end{choices}

    %Q41
    \question O ganho do sinal recebido com polarização circular recebe um sinal por uma antena com polarização linear comparado com um sinal recebido pela mesma antena com polarização circular será:
    \begin{choices}
        \choice Máximo.
        \CC Zero.
        \choice 3 dB a menos
        \choice 3 dB a mais
    \end{choices}

    %Q42
    \question Quando o diametro de uma antena é dobrado, o ganho da antena:
    \begin{choices}
        \choice Reduz pela metade
        \choice Aumenta 3dB
        \choice Reduz 3dB
        \CC Aumenta 6dB
    \end{choices}

    %Q43
    \question A impedância intrínseca no espaço livre tem o valor igual a:
    \begin{choices}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \choice $75 \Omega$
        \choice $73 \Omega$
        \CC $377 \Omega$
        \choice $300 \Omega$
    \end{multicols}
    \end{choices}




\end{questions}

\end{multicols*}

\bigskip

\showallanswers

\end{document}
```

EDIT1: The @Joseph fix partially the code and answer will print. But the answer key overlap text outside the paper.

EDIT2: One more help with @Joseph fix the code but the answerkey remains on one column
[image]

[image]

Comment: The issue seems to be with the definition of your `\CC` command, especially when you use it as the final choice option within a `multicol` environment. To debug your code you can delete the first 14 questions and just keep the final one.

Comment: so this alias havent fix? Do I have use CorrectChoice?

Comment: I don't know. I left my comment so that others reading your question and trying to help can more quickly isolate the problem.

Comment: @miguel747, see my update. there was an `\unvbox` missing.

Comment: Ty @Joseph. the code fits the page properly but the answer key is a one column and doesnt fill the right side of paper. See the picture.

Comment: @miguel747, the code works fine as per your original question. As for the "one-column", you can change it yourself, as you did with the questions.

Comment: ok @Joseph. You are right. Thanks for your help man. Gday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something weird that you didn't copy properly when you patched your document from various sources. I simplified your example.

```
  \documentclass[11pt]{exam}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[brazil]{babel}
    \pagestyle{headandfoot}
    \lfoot{}
    \cfoot{}
    \rfoot[]{\small pag. \thepage\ of \numpages}
    \footrule

%%%%The following sets up a box to save all the answer information into.
%% Give credit when  credit is due:%% 
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238153/multiple-choice-answer-key-in-exam-package-at-the-end-of-document


\newbox\allanswers
\setbox\allanswers=\vbox{}

\newenvironment{answer}
{%
  \global\setbox\allanswers=\vbox\bgroup %
  \unvbox\allanswers%
    \thequestion -- \thechoice\\
}%
{%
  \egroup%
}

\newcommand{\CC}{\CorrectChoice \leavevmode\begin{answer}\end{answer}}% New command \CC replaces \CorrectChoice from exam.sty and saves answers in the box \allanswers .


\newcommand{\showallanswers}{\par\medskip\unvbox\allanswers} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15354/9424


    \renewcommand{\thequestion}{\bfseries\arabic{question}}
    \renewcommand\choicelabel{(\alph{choice})}

   \renewcommand{\thequestion}{\bfseries\arabic{question}}
    \renewcommand\choicelabel{(\alph{choice})}

    \renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{30pt}%
    }
    \renewcommand{\choiceshook}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{20pt}%
    }

    \setlength{\topmargin}{-1.8cm} \setlength{\textheight}{10in}
    \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
    \extrafootheight{.75in}

    \begin{document}


\begin{questions}
    %Q1
    \question Um capacitor $C$ é submetido a uma tensão $V$. A energia armazenada no capacitor vale:

    \begin{oneparchoices}
               \choice $CV^2$
                \CC $0.5CV^2$
                \choice $2CV^2$
                \choice $CV$
            \end{oneparchoices}
    %Q2

\end{questions}


\showallanswers


\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of use \begin{choices} you replaced by begin{oneparchoices}?

Comment: I just made it simpler. This environment doesn't matter in the result and it wasn't that that was interfering.

Comment: sorry for this paste code. I will be more carefully next time.

Comment: @miguel747, no problem. you can mark the answer as accepted if it suited your needs.

Comment: your solution works fine even if use choice environment and CC. Probably your \newenvironment{answer} fixed the problem. Last question, the answer key go to the new page doesnt close to "Respostas (responda sem colar):". Maybe due to 30 questions it doesnt fit on one collumn. I use another section to write the answer. The correct code is here: https://pastebin.com/fVifFCpz and screen https://imgur.com/a/rxyxehP

Comment: I got the overlap text on asnwer key. Look that. https://imgur.com/xIX23TA